# No more get_option('date_time') in Wordpress 5.5?

Tags: php, post-meta, options, date-time

The template I'm using outputs the date of a post using:

```php
echo get_the_date( get_option( 'date_time' ) );
```

I was wondering why this output is now (after upgrade to WP 5.5) not working anymore?

---

A fast fix is using the option `date_format`:

```php
echo get_the_date( get_option( 'date_format' ) );
```

I looked into Wordpress Developer https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/#source looks like it suppose also to work when the option 'date_time' is empty:

```php
function get_the_date( $format = '', $post = null ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );
 
    if ( ! $post ) {
        return false;
    }
 
    if ( '' === $format ) { // <-- check for empty value
        $the_date = get_post_time( get_option( 'date_format' ), false, $post, true );
    } else {
        $the_date = get_post_time( $format, false, $post, true );
    }
 
    return apply_filters( 'get_the_date', $the_date, $format, $post );
}
```

**Why does the output of `get_the_date(get_option('date_time'))` in the template doesnt work with Wordpress 5.5?**

Comment: `get_option()` returns a saved setting value, and there's no setting in WordPress called `date_time`. Where is that coming from?

Comment: The option is from the template I'm using. The attribute was empty before too but it still gave me the date as output. I just tried to understand why it fails with WP 5.5. I setup my local system now with PHP 7.4 and I'll try to debug it...

Comment: @JacobPeattie I found the problem, see answer below. No clue how to file a bug report for the wordpress core...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the issue, it's like I thought. The problem is that `get_option( 'date_time' )` return just `false`.

The change happened in the funtion [**`get_the_date()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/).

In Wordpress **5.4** is looked like that in the [general-template.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4-branch/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2524):

```php
function get_the_date( $format = '', $post = null ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );

    if ( ! $post ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( '' == $format ) {
        $the_date = get_post_time( get_option( 'date_format' ), false, $post, true );
    } else {
        $the_date = get_post_time( $format, false, $post, true );
    }


    return apply_filters( 'get_the_date', $the_date, $format, $post );
}
```

Since Wordpress **5.5** the [general-template.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.5-branch/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2521) looks like that:

```php
function get_the_date( $format = '', $post = null ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );

    if ( ! $post ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( '' === $format ) {
        $the_date = get_post_time( get_option( 'date_format' ), false, $post, true );
    } else {
        $the_date = get_post_time( $format, false, $post, true );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'get_the_date', $the_date, $format, $post );
}
```

The difference is just in the type true comparison operators

```php
// Wordpress 5.4
if ( '' == $format )

// vs

// Wordpress 5.5
if ( '' === $format )
```

---

#### Bugfix?!

I think the correct solution would be to check for and empty or `false` `$format`. Something like that:

```php
if ( '' === $format || false === $format )
```

Comment: This is not a bug in WordPress. It's a bug in your template. The documentation for `get_the_date()` clearly states that the first parameter is a string, but your template is passing `false`. The bug fix would be for your template to remove the option that doesn't exist, or to set the default value to be a string: `echo get_the_date( get_option( 'date_format', '' ) );`

Comment: @JacobPeattie it's a bug of the template, but also a bug of the core! I created a ticket and pull request here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51184

Comment: This was fix in Wordpress Core 5.5.1